# Does changing the login password also change the keyring password?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, gnome-keyring

I use a computer where I'm not the admin, so my password could be changed at any time. My question is, does changing the login password to my account also change the password to the keyring? I don't want the admin looking at my Chrome passwords.

Comment: Removed the second question. Mostly laziness on my part, since it's something I can test pretty easily :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known facts about the process:

- The procedure to change the account password includes a hook to update the keyring password in the process.
- The keyring password can only be changed (successfully), when the previous password is supplied to the process that changes it, since the key securing the keyring needs to be decrypted with the old and re-encrypted with the new password.

Assumption about the "attacker":

- A system administrator running `sudo passwd degru` (or doing something equivalent) doesn't (typically) know the previous account password for user `degru`.

Conclusion: The keyring password is only updated during an account password change, when the account owner changes the password. The system administrator cannot decrypt the keyring simply by changing the account password.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Does this change if the password is changed through the Ubuntu user settings GUI?

Comment: No. The process is fundamentally the same and changing the keyring password still requires knowledge of its current password, no matter how it is changed.